# Will Compiz and CCSM be discontinued?

Tags: compiz

It is so much easier to drag and drop windows across virtual desktops using  Compiz cube on any desktop compared to Gnome shell.

Will Ubuntu continue to develop or at least offer support for Compiz and CCSM in the future?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/905409/will-unity-still-be-available-for-download-after-ubuntu-18-10, https://askubuntu.com/questions/900788/is-there-an-active-unity-7-fork

Comment: @muru Thanks, I narrowed it down to Compiz since I haven't really heard anything about Compiz being discontinued, only Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical has never supported CCSM (officially) - the package is in Universe. And since Unity is not the only software which depends on Compiz (MATE uses it as well, see `apt-cache rdepends compiz-core`), it's likely that the compiz packages will all get shunted off to Universe and stay there, maintained by volunteers, just like, say, [the XFCE packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xfwm4).