# What's going to happen to the Unity desktop environment and default Ubuntu version?

Tags: unity, upgrade, desktop-environments

I've heard that Ubuntu 18.04 will be using GNOME desktop by default. So, what is going to happen to Unity?

- Will Ubuntu 16.04 (with Unity) receive updates until 2021 for Unity desktop?
- What desktop environments will we get while upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04?
- Will Unity be dead?
- Will there be an Ubuntu Unity Flavor?

And my major question is:

- Can I still be able to Download Ubuntu Unity 17.10 or need to upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to get 17.10 with unity ??

Comment: There won't be any Ubuntu Unity 17.10, the switch is happening right now. Ubuntu 17.10 will come with GNOME as default.

Comment: Related: [Is there an active Unity 7 fork?](https://askubuntu.com/q/900788/301745)

Comment: IMO you should just go with gnome wayland ASAP. I am sure there will be a custom theme in ubuntu and to be honest it is easier to customize gnome, not that you can do so, but many people can.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen GNOME Wayland doesn't work YET. They're hoping to get it working for the 17.10 release, but 17.04 versions just don't work yet.

Comment: It works on Fedora, which is where I am posting from. Thanks for the update re: ubuntu.

Comment: GNOME on Wayland is the default for 17.10, but it's possible to switch back to the X version very easily if there is some problem with it on your video chipset.

Comment: The answers Given below are still not satisfying

Answer (score 14):

Unity will eventually be removed from the archives. The default experience on Ubuntu is moving to GNOME. There is no more "Ubuntu GNOME" flavor of Ubuntu. You can either upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, install 17.10 from scratch, or if you run LTS, stick to 16.04 and upgrade when 18.04 is ready.

You can install GNOME directly from the archive already, with no need to re-install your system. You can simply install the `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` package on 16.04, to get the standard Ubuntu GNOME install in 16.04.

Ubuntu 16.04 is an LTS and will continue to receive updates until May 2021, when it will be End of Life. However, unless there is a major bug affecting the Unity software, it's unlikely there will be many updates for it.

Answer (score 4):

Your information is not valid. Ubuntu is switching to gnome in October, in version 17.10. If you like your unity, you can keep older version, nothing will push you into downloading new one.

Since 17.10, Ubuntu will not be avilable with Unity, but some kind of Ubuntu specific gnome version. You can keep it, or you can still download another Desktop enviroment at your will and replace it with Ubuntu stock gnome.

You can read a bit here:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-gnome-shell-ambiance

OR here

https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-17-10-release-features/

Sorry for not posting any official declarations, Im not sure if there are any.

Comment: So http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk is trusted site ??

Comment: I have not written that it is, I just wanted to post some source of reading where can he start. Plus the text inside is not a complete joke.

Comment: I know It's not a joke. I am reading http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/ from long time but don't know that it is trusted or not. Don't get offended

Comment: The GNOME in 17.10 is not a "special Ubuntu version." it is simply standard GNOME with some Ubuntu-specific defaults and extensions. One can still configure whatever extensions they want for gnome shell.

Comment: @SMITPATIL omgubuntu is usually reliable, just keep in mind that it's doing journalism and might do not all-reliable stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happen if I upgrade 16.04 to 18.04. But unity7 is not yet dead. `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package still there. And community developed iso available to preconfigured unity desktop. I just tried in virtualbox. It's working.
See: http://people.ubuntu.com/~twocamels/